# Apex: Making key lowercased in json serialized version of object

Tags: apex, json, serialization

The usual way to serialize hierarchy of objects in json looks like this in Apex:

```
String json = JSON.serialize(rootNode);
```

My requirement is to send this json to our external system. But they want to have all keys to be in lowercase in that json (just keys, but not values, so lowercasing whole json doesn't work here).

So is there any way to hook into json serialization process and make some transformation of the keys? Can't do anything with rootNode object itself, it's actually the whole huge hierarchy of objects - would be insane to traverse through it somehow to fix keys(

Comment: If the rootNode is from an Apex class, simply change the property names in the class to lowercase. Where to rootNode come from?

Comment: @Eric rootNode is an apex class, but it contains references to other apex classes, collections of sobjects etc. It's like the root of quite huge hierarchy of other apex classes and sobjects linked together in quite chaotic way. I need to have lowercased properties for the whole hierarchy, you see. Unfortunately, it's not just about simple apex class with few string properties in it(